# Latex: verbatim content on one page

Tags: latex

I use latex for my reports. Recently I have got an issue when my verbatim environment was split into several pages, where there were pictures in between. I would like to keep verbatim environment in one page only. Content of verbatim fits one page. Is this possible?

```
\begin{verbatim}
something unchanged here 
\end{verbatim}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are packages that provide verbatim environments with more features such as avoiding page breaks. With the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/) package:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[samepage=true]
...
\end{Verbatim}
```

A universal way of preventing page breaks is to use a `minipage` environment, but it's not optimal — see the [Tex FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=nopagebrk).